# How can i fix "googlebot can't access site" issue?

Tags: googlebot, google-search-console

I found many question related to this:"over the last 24 hours, googlebot encountered 118 error while attempting to connect your site. your site overall connection failure rate is 8.9%."

But I am not getting any exact solution for this.

I have tested all & everything is working fine. I am not understood why it's showing? What is the exact solution for this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try some "dns health check" tool to test your DNS configuration.

I'm experiencing this error randomly last month and still did not found correct solution. After some research i found that this error is probably connected with some network & DNS resolution problems that are very hard to diagnose & solve.

Also there are some threds on Google product forums where their stuff confirmed randomly having problems with this message [link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/webmasters/Matt_Cutts%2420on%2420our%2420end/webmasters/mY75bBb3c3c/M_gFhlWeQ-wJ)

Comment: Thanks, but I already gone through this.Is there any other solutions